# Як правильно "камінчик" чи "каміньчик"?

Tags: правопис

Занадто поширена помилка у правописі цього слова. Тож як правильно? І яким правилом українського правопису це можна пояснити?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Згідно з чинним — 2015 — правописом: **[камінчик](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA)**. Тому що після **н** і перед **ч**.

[§ 17. Коли Ь не пишеться](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par17)

> **2.** Після **н** перед **ж**, **ч**, **ш**, **щ** та перед суфіксами **‑ств**(**о**), **‑ськ**(**ий**): *інженер, інший, кінчик, менший, тонший, Уманщина; волинський, громадянський, освітянський, селянський; громадянство, селянство*. Але: *бриньчати, доньчин, няньчин, няньчити та ін.*, бо в твірних іменниках між приголосними виступає **ь**: *бренькіт, донька, нянька.*

Comment: Але суперечить йому інше правило. Якщо знак м'якшення уживається у формі Н. в. іменника, то він зберігається й у всіх інших відмінках . Отож, якщо подумати, то в Н. в. камінь. Це означає, що за логікою правильно каміньчик. Як це пояснити? Яким, тоді, правилом користуватися?

Comment: @ІринаВолодченко, *камінчик* — це не відмінкова форма від *камінь*. У цьому випадку навряд чи можна застосувати це правило.

Answer (score 2):

Підтримуючи відповідь [@Анна Солнцева](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/1452/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0) з посиланням на правило чинного правопису, доповню роз'ясненням професора І.П. Ющука, який, на мою думку, завжди складним правилам знаходить прості пояснення і підказки для кращого запам'ятовування.

[**ЮЩУК І. П. Практикум з правопису і граматики української мови**.— К.:
Освіта, 2012.— 270 с.](https://ushchuk.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/d196.pdf#page=31), (*увага - посилання на файл у форматі .pdf*), зокрема, § 16. Вживання м’якого знака (стор. 31-35):

> М’якість приголосних перед голосними [а], [у], [e], [і], [о]
>   позначаємо відповідно буквами **я, ю, є, і, ь**: [синˊа] синя, [синˊу]
>   синю, [синˊе] синє, [синˊі] сині, [синˊого] синього.
>
> Для позначення м’якості приголосних **у кінці слова і перед наступним
>   приголосним** служить буква **ь**. При цьому треба мати на увазі, що
>   м’якими в цій позиції можуть бути лише зубні приголосні (див. § 15,
>   пп. 2, 3). Отже, й **м’який  знак тут можна ставити лише після семи
>   букв д, т, з, с, ц, л, н** (*“де ти з’їси ці лини”*).
>
> 1. **У кінці слова м’якість зубних приголосних завжди позначаємо м’яким знаком (за фонетичним принципом)**: *молодь, мить, скрізь,
>      звідкілясь, вітрець, жаль, осторонь*.
>
>    Причому в дієсловах перед часткою **-ся (-сь)** м’який знак
>      зберігається:
>      *будують — будуються, стань — станься і станьсь. піднось—підносься (але: піднісся, бо підніс*).
> 2. **У середині слова м’якість зубних приголосних позначається м’яким знаком лише перед твердими нешиплячими**: *їдьте, боротьба, призьба,
>      товариський, козацький, ненька*.
>
>    Причому м’який знак у таких словах завжди зберігається:
>
>    а) при відмінюванні: *у боротьбі, у жменьці, неньці, товариські,
>      козацькі; але: [масˊцˊі] масці, бо маска; [хатинˊцˊі] хатинці, бо
>      хатинка*;
>
>    б) в утворених від них присвійних прикметниках: н*еньчин, Таньчин.
>      Зіньчин, Прісьчин; але: Маланчин, бо Маланка*.
> 3. **Перед постійно м’якими, пом’якшеними і шиплячими м’який знак не ставиться:** *[сˊв’ато] свято, [дзˊв’акнути] дзвякнути, [сˊнˊіг] сніг,
>      велетенський (хоч велетень), кінський (хоч кінь), безбатченко (хоч
>      батько), **промінчик (хоч промінь)***.
>
>    Проте як виняток м’який знак у цій позиції ставиться:
>
>    а) після букви л; *читальня, гуцульський, Гуцульщина (але: [голˊцˊі]
>      голці, бо голка; [рибалˊцˊі] рибалці, бо рибалка)*;
>
>    б) у словах *тьмяний, різьбяр, няньчити, бриньчати, а також женьшень, 
>      Маньчжурія*.
> 4. **Після букв, що позначають губні, піднебінні і задньоротові, м’який знак не ставиться**: *кров, сім, ідеш, повір, (багато) облич
>      (хоч обличчя), роздоріж (хоч роздоріжжя), зір (хоч зоря), бур (хоч
>      буря); поставмо, насипмо, гіркий, ларки (хоч ларьок), чотирма (хоч
>      чотирьох)*.
>
>    **Після р м’який знак ставимо лише перед о та як виняток у псевдонімі Горький** (хоч вимовляємо твердо: [горкий]).

**Отже, робимо висновок, що у випадку з *камінчиком* застосовний пункт 3 (м’який знак не ставиться, бо всередині слова й перед шиплячим ч, наводиться дуже схожий приклад із *промінчиком*.)**

І бонусом фірмова кмітлинка від пана професора:

> ***Та це ж просто...***
>
> *Допитливий*.  М’який знак у кінці слова після зубних ставити просто: чуєш м’яку вимову — пиши. Важче з ним у середині слова: хоч і чуєш
>   м’якість, а ти ще подумай, чи ставити його тут, чи ні.
>
> *Кмітливий.* А я собі це спростив до формул: **ньк, нсь, нш**, де буквою **к** позначив
>   **твердий нешиплячий**, буквами **сь** — **м’який**, буквою **ш** — **шиплячий**, а буквою **н** — **будь-який зубний**. **Отже, м’який знак маю право ставити лише перед твердими нешиплячими.** Правда, є ще
>   винятки та буква л, після якої м’який знак ставимо й перед м’якими,
>   пом’якшеними та шиплячими.

Comment: Від скороченьа ваша відповідь лише б виграла, залиште в перемові потрібного шматка.